# Passing arguments to executor.submit() - unicode object not callable

Tags: python, flask, executor

I have a Flask view that handles a background process, like so:

```
@app.route('/playlist')
def playlist(tracks):
    executor.submit(build_playlist,tracks=tracks)
    return 'Building playlist...'
```

and this view function calls the following method:

```
def build_playlist(tracks):
   (...process tracks...)
```

this is where the process is called down the app:

```
@app.route('/handle_playlists', methods=['POST'])
def handle_playlist():
    jukebox = ['track1', 'track2', 'track3']
    tracks = random.choice(jukebox)
    playlist(tracks) <------------------------
```

If I call `playlist()` I get the error:

```
`'unicode' object is not callable`
```

but it works if I call `build_playlist(tracks)` directly, so I must be making a silly mistake with `executor.submit()`.

what am I missing here?

Comment: Did I understand correctly? Do you call `playlist` endpoint from `handle_playlists` endpoint? If yes why you do like this?

Comment: because 'handle' endpoints merely handle POST data, in my app. it is not an endpoint where a template is rendered for the user. it is supposed to trigger background processes and such.